# Symfony i18n dictionaries in database

Tags: symfony1, internationalization, symfony-1.4

I've implemented i18n for my website with doctrine driver: dictionaries are stored in the database, but they are also cached (default driver). I've also implemented an interface for a user to manage the dictionaries and translations. Now, how you do think I should write new translations to cache? Should I give the user a link to clear the cache (which calls cache:clear task)? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory you should only need to clear the i18n cache. Those would be stored in /cache/appname/envname/i18n.

You could also completely disable the cache for i18n in factories.yml:

```
all:
  i18n:
    param:
      cache:
        class: sfNoCache
```

Comment: Disabling the cache results in additional database queries overhead. I've implemented an action specifically for clearing the i18n cache and it works perfectly for me.